# Android rotate ViewPager Image manually (via button click) without rotating phone

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

How would I rotate a ViewPager image via button click (say clockwise)? This way I can set the phone to portrait and let the users rotate the image themselves while viewing.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your phone, Android actually completely redraws your activity to fit the landscape mode. This results in two instance of your activity in your application.

Now, if you have some kind of static variable instance but the class itself is a none-static inner class, it will keep a reference to your activity and prevent the GC to collect to, causing the most common memory leak with orientation rotation.

To fix this, you can either change your variable to non-static, or your inner class to static as well.

If your problem still exist, create a heap dump, and trace your object's path to GC root excluding weak references, in the Eclipse memory analyser. There is a great video explaining [memory leak in android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) in the 2011 google I/O.